# dificullty while using two databases in the spring hibernate application

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-transactions, sessionfactory

I am trying to use 2 databases in my spring project. It is working fine if I use 1 database but when add other databases I am getting following error message.

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread
```

dispatcher-servlet

```
    <beans:bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="sample" />
        <beans:property name="annotatedClasses">
            <beans:list>

                                <beans:value>com.kendoui.spring.models.Constraint</beans:value>

            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
        <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
            <beans:props>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect
                </beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</beans:prop>

            </beans:props>
        </beans:property>

    </beans:bean>


    <beans:bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />

    </beans:bean>


    <beans:bean id="Ascent" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" />
        <beans:property name="url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=Ascent;" />
        <beans:property name="username" value="sa" />
        <beans:property name="password" value="abc123" />
        <beans:property name="maxActive" value="1" />
        <beans:property name="maxIdle" value="1" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="sessionFactory2" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="Ascent" />
        <beans:property name="annotatedClasses">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:value>com.kendoui.spring.models.ItemOperationSequence</beans:value>
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
        <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
            <beans:props>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</beans:prop>

            </beans:props>
        </beans:property>

    </beans:bean>


    <beans:bean id="transactionManager2" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory2" />

    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Enable annotation driven transactions. Required by getCurrentSession(). -->
    <tx:annotation-driven/>
```

DAO implemantation

```
@Transactional("transactionManager2")
    @Component
    public class ItemOprSeqDaoImpl implements ItemOprSeqDao {

        @Autowired

        private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

        @Override
        public List<ItemOperationSequence> getList(String Itemcode) {
            Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

            String queryStr= "select * from [@is_itemtrvoprdetails]";
            Query query= session.createSQLQuery(queryStr).addEntity(ItemOperationSequence.class);
            List <ItemOperationSequence> d=query.list();
            return d;
        }

    }
```

I tried many different things but it is not working.
I tried using `<beans:qualifier value="Ascent" />` in my servlet
and 
`@Qualifier(value="SessionFactory2")` in my DAO
but nothing seems to work.

Anyone knows the answer to this problem. I would really appreciate if you could help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: <tx:annotation-driven/> should be defined twice. <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager2"/> and <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

Comment: Do you have separate Entities and Repositories for each database?

Comment: I am just using entities.

Answer (score 0):

`<tx:annotation-driven/>` should be declared twice once for each transaction manager.

`<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager2"/>`

and

`<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>`

Also add `@Qualifier` for

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier(value="SessionFactory2")
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
```

Comment: I tried doing this but I am getting the exception : org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a ChainedTransactionManager with both HibernateTransactionManagers as input.
I am not used to spring xml configuration, but it should look like this.
Than just use only @Transactional without a value.

```
<beans:bean id="transactionManager1" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />

</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="transactionManager2" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory2" />

</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.data.transaction.ChainedTransactionManager">
    <beans:constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <beans:ref bean="transactionManager1" />
            <beans:ref bean="transactionManager2" />
        </list>
    </beans:constructor-arg>
</beans:bean>
```

Comment: I tried using this but I got the exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.data.transaction.ChainedTransactionManager.  I included the jar spring-data-neo4j-tx-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar but still it is giving the same exception.

Comment: Arg your not using spring-data my bad sorry.

Comment: Ohh I am not using it.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I solved the problem by doing this.
first declared transaction-manager

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager1"/>
```

Then in my DAO used

```
     @Transactional("transactionManager2")
    @Component
    public class ItemOprSeqDaoImpl implements ItemOprSeqDao {

        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("sessionFactory2")
        private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
        //then rest of the code
}
```

Its working fine now. Thanks you guys for your help.